# How does ARM MCU find my relocated vector table?

Tags: vector, linker, cortex-m

I'm using an NXP Kinetis K64 ARM Cortex M4 MCU.  I successfully altered the linker configuration file to move my vector table to address 0x8000 (instead of the 0x0000 default).  When I tell the CodeWarrior 10.6 debugger to break at the start of the code, it stops at the top of the boot.S file as expected.  But it dawned on me, *HOW* did the MCU/debugger find the code since the flash memory is empty (0xFF) from address 0x0000 to 0x7FFF and the VTOR register shows as 0x0?!

I looked through the datasheets of both the ARM M4 core and the NXP K64, but they don't answer this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably due to the settings of your Debug Configurations in CodeWarrior. In Debugger tab, if **Initialized program counter at** is ticked as shown below, the debugger will give Program Counter, at reset, the address of *"the top of the boot.S file"*, which is the **Program entry point**. The normal sequence of finding the vector table is skipped.

Your program will not run without the debugger.
[image: screenshot]

Further details about the CodeWarrior Debugger can be found [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/CW_ARMv7_Targeting_Manual.pdf)

Comment: That makes perfect sense and is confirmed by experimentation.  Thank you for your reply and the URL. 
If the normal sequence of finding the vector table at boot-up is by reading 

the VTOR register, how can that be set beforehand--via the linker file?

Comment: The reset value of VTOR register is always 0x0. You will have to set the value of VTOR every single time after reset, and do so in the default Reset Handler, of which the address is stored at location 0x4.

Comment: I see; so there is no way to leave 0x0000 to 0x7FFF empty (including the 0x0004) and have my code execute at 0x8000 while detached from a programmer.  I'll just have to be aware of that.  Thanks again.